# Disable "TODO" warning before commit

Tags: pycharm

When I commit code containing TODO comments through PyCharm it asks me if I'd like to review these comments. I don't and I doubt I ever will.

[image]

How can this extra step be disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this exists on all versions of PyCharm (I have the full-blown professional version), but after you click on "commit changes" you should see a checkbox on the right side that allows you to check or not check TODO items before commit.
[image]

Comment: Sometimes the answer hides in plain sight! Thanks. By the way, I use the professional version too, so no idea how it behaves ind the Community version. I'd think it's the same.

Comment: The Community edition behavior is fully equal with regards to version control support.